# Duplicate code when git merge (auto-merge)

Tags: git

I noticed that when I merge using `git pull`, sometimes there could be undesirable outcome on my code. For example,

**on remote branch:**

```
function(){
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
  functionThree();
}
```

**on local branch:**

```
function(){

  functionThree();
  functionTwo();
}
```

**after merge:**

```
function(){
  functionThree();
  functionTwo();
  functionThree();
}
```

Above is a simplified example to try to illustrate what I experienced. I tend moved the code around with empty lines when I code and I don't merge with the remote branch (master) often, I'm not sure if that has any effect when merging. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your local code conflicts with remote one, you should resolve it manually instead of auto-merging.

Comment: manually as in going through everything line-by-line?

Comment: when I merge, it doesn't raise any conflicts